# Firebase database listener get values only when change

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a node that I refresh every three days with some key-value pairs in my firebase realtime database. I want my app to get the new values only when I make changes in this node (so about every three days). I currently use this code to test :

```
    mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("test").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    Log.d("thatsdatasnapshot", "thatsdatasnapshot = " + tsLong.toString());
Log.d("thatsdatasnapshot", "thatsdatasnapshot = " + dataSnapshot.toString());
                }
```

My issue is that my logs in this listener print very often even I don't change anything in my node, for example everytime I start the app. So I guess that all the values of my node are downloaded "very often", not only when I make change in my database. Am I wrong ? How to download the values of my node only when there is a change ? I thought it was what addValueEventListener() should do but I have a doubt when I see my logs printed so often.

Thank you,

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `addValueEventListener` is only triggered when values in the realtime db change during your current run of the app, such as for every `mRef.push()` or `mRef.child("someChild").setValue()` method call in your app.

I had almost the same kind of problem with firebase realtime database and in the end, i resorted to creating an `AsyncTask` to update what you have to update during your app's runtime.

What you have to do is create an `AsyncTask` and make a REST call to your Firebase Database, and use it to update.